# {0:N0} format in kendo grid footer , MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to show the aggregate of my grid's column, by `{0:N0}` format in a client footer

```
    columns.Bound(p => p.DoctorCost).Format("{0:N0}").Title("Totall")
                                      .ClientFooterTemplate("#= sum # ").Format("{0:N0}");
```

but its not working ...its showing the value without any format.

Answer (score 2):

i found it :

```
 .ClientFooterTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:N0}', sum)#")
```